# DexieJS How to assign a result to a variable?

Tags: dexie

I have been trying to figure out this thing but I have no luck on searching over google. I have been trying to assign the result to a variable but always return some kind of a promise object is I got it right. Here are my codes:-

```
console.log(db.table.count( result => result )); //  total always show some object

db.table.count( result => console.log(result) ); // this will show the total count.
```

it happens the same when I do the following:-

```
console.log(db.table.toArray( result => result ));  // list will show some object
db.table.toArray( result => console.log(result) ); // will display the actual data
```

So i have to workaround it and should be the worst workaround ( at least to me ):-

```
let list = [ ];

await db.table.toArray( result => { list = result });

console.log(list) // then this i get the data
```

is there a way to assign the variable directly? Like :-

```
let list = db.table.toArray( result => result ) ??
```

This is my main issue now, which my coding turn out so ugly. I have to reuse a lot of same block of codes instead of putting them into a function that i can call for doing the same thing. I cannot create a function for redundant code due to my skills level on javascript.

Please advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I would do this

```js
let list = await db.table.toArray();
```